# Removing hyperlinks from PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to make PDF files. Specifically, the source of these PDF files is Outlook emails. So there are mailto:, website, etc links everywhere. These links don't show with an underline, they just link to a site when you hover over them and click. I looked at this question: [Remove hyperlinks from a PDF document (iTextSharp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871906/remove-hyperlinks-from-a-pdf-document-itextsharp) and tried both solutions, however neither removed the links. Can someone offer some advice on how to remove hyperlinks from a PDF **USING** iTextSharp?

I am using Adobe Acrobat Standard X.

Example: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05714019267649134441

Comment: Which program displays those links? If you are seeing them in e.g. Adobe Reader, they might very well not be in the PDF: Adobe Reader itself recognizes some URLs in the PDF text and makes them clickable! If in doubt, please provide a sample PDF to illustrate the issue.

Comment: It's Adobe Acrobat Standard X. Added download link for an example. Hover over the email addresses or links. When I ran the code in the question asked above, no annotations were found in this document.

Comment: As @mkl said, in Acrobat/Reader if you go to Edit, Preferences, General you can uncheck "Create links from URLs" and the links will go away. I don't know if there's a programmatic way to tell the renderer to not do that automatically.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. Glad to know it's pretty much out of my control. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a preference in Acrobat/Reader. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> General tab -> **Uncheck "Create links from URLs"**. The best part is, this setting will stay in effect while opening different documents. Credits to Chris Haas.