# PdfArray.remove() is not removing all annotations

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to remove all annotations from a PDF.  I'm using this code:

```
void removeAnnotations(string inputPath,string outputPath)
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPath);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));
            PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
            PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < annotArray.Size; i++)
            {
                annotArray.Remove(i);   
            }
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
```

When I first create `annotArray`, it has 217 items.  After the for-loop of `annotArray.Remove()`, it has 108 items, and I can still see some callouts and lines on the PDF generated at `outputPath`.  It's not immediately clear to me what the remaining items have in common, as to why they were skipped by `annotArray.Remove()`.  How can I remove every annotation?

Comment: `itextsharp` is deprecated use `iText 7` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have 10 elements in an array:

```
array = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
```

You then loop over the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Size; i++)
{
    array.Remove(i);   
}
```

Then this is what happens step by step:

**step 0**

Remove element 0.
Result: `[b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]`

**step 1**

Remove element 1.
Result: `[b, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]`

**step 2**

Remove element 2.
Result: `[b, d, f, g, h, i, j]`

**step 3**

Remove element 3.
Result: `[b, d, f, h, i, j]`

**step 4**

Remove element 4.
Result: `[b, d, f, h, j]`

**step 5**

Remove element 5. There is no element 5, so there's nothing to remove. Result: `[b, d, f, h, j]`

**step 6 to 9**

Remove element 6 to 9. There is no element 6 to 9, so there's nothing to remove. Result: `[b, d, f, h, j]`

Although my array only counts 10 elements whereas yours counts 128, the principle is the same: you aren't removing all the annotations due to a logical error in your code. Another type of array would throw an array out of bounds exception, but `PdfArray` doesn't do that because to be more tolerant towards faulty PDFs with incomplete arrays.

You could fix your code like this:

```
int n = annotArray.Size;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    annotArray.Remove(0);   
}
```

Or, as you found out yourself, you can remove all annotations at once:

```
pdfReader.RemoveAnnotations();
```

Comment: How to shoot a moving target... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Removing all annotations turns out to be fairly easy:

```
void removeAnnotations(string inputPath,string outputPath)
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPath);
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));

            pdfReader.RemoveAnnotations();
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
```

Comment: That's indeed easy, but that doesn't explain why your initial attempt didn't work. As it turns out, you've made a logical error by moving forward in an array while removing objects from that array.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used itextSharp. I was curious why it shouldn't remove.Code looks okay though. I googled and found something that might be of your interest. Hope it help.

> You cannot delete the annotations "in place" with
>   iTextSharp. You have to create a new PDF based on the original, and the way
>   to do this is to open the original with PDFReader, use RemoveAt to get rid
>   of the undesirable annotations in memory, then use PDFstamper or PDFcopy to
>   make a new PDF based on what's left.

[Remove Annotation from PDF](http://itextsharp-questions.narkive.com/xZd2BnHq/re-move-stamp-annotations-from-pdf)

[Remove Annotation using PDF Object Number](http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/Remove-Annotation-using-PDF-Object-Number-td2831.html)

[Remove hyperlinks from a PDF document (iTextSharp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871906/remove-hyperlinks-from-a-pdf-document-itextsharp)

[How do I remove link annotations from a PDF using iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974031/how-do-i-remove-link-annotations-from-a-pdf-using-itext)

Comment: The code doesn't look OK because it contains an error against elementary logic. What you write is true, but the OP is already doing that. He uses `PdfStamper` to create a new PDF.